# How come a is b output in python 3.7 is different from previous versions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Can someone please explain to me, why is `a is b` outputs differ in python 3.7 from previous versions? like in the following cases for example:

```py
>>> a, b = 257, 257
>>> a is b
True  # Python < 3.7
False # Python 3.7

>>> a = 257; b = 257;
>>> a is b
True  # Python < 3.7
True  # Python 3.7
```

this behavior cover strings too:

```py
>>> a, b = "wtf!", "wtf!"
>>> a is b
True  # Python < 3.7
False # Python >= 3.7

>>> 'a' * 20 is 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
True  # in all Python versions
>>> 'a' * 21 is   'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
False # Python < 3.7
True  # Python >= 3.7
```

Answer (score 2):

A Python implementation is free to share immutable objects or not, at its own discretion, for reasons that might not be apparent to us.  I don't know why Python 3.7 behaves differently than Python 3.6.  Possibly a change in the peephole optimizer, or the interning of immutable values.

The behavior change doesn't matter. Real programs don't make these kinds of tests, precisely because they are about internal implementation details.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the python 3.6 behavior. It was a typo and I fixed it. I think it is quite important to be aware of such behaviors as such simple differences can lead to bigger problems.

Comment: The important thing is to not use "is" for this kind of comparison.